# Find if one integer array is a permutation of other

Tags: arrays

Given two integer arrays of size N, design an algorithm to determine whether one is a permutation of the other. That is, do they contain exactly the same entries but, possibly, in a different order.

I can think of two ways:
Sort them and compare : O(N.log N + N)

Check if the array have same number of integers and the sum of these integers is same, then XOR both the arrays and see if the result is 0. This is O(N). I am not sure if this method will eliminate false positives completely. Thoughts. Better algorithms?

Comment: What do you mean by "XOR both the arrays"? In most languages I am familiar with XOR is only defined for integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Check if the array have same number of integers and the sum of these integers is same, then XOR both the arrays and see if the result is 0.

This doesn't work. Example:

```
a = [1,6]  length(a) = 2, sum(a) = 7, xor(a) = 7
b = [3,4]  length(b) = 2, sum(b) = 7, xor(b) = 7
```

Others have already suggested `HashMap` for an O(n) solution.

Here's an O(n) solution in C# using a `Dictionary<T, int>`:

```
bool IsPermutation<T>(IList<T> values1, IList<T> values2)
{
    if (values1.Count != values2.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }

    Dictionary<T, int> counts = new Dictionary<T, int>();
    foreach (T t in values1)
    {
        int count;
        counts.TryGetValue(t, out count);
        counts[t] = count + 1;
    }

    foreach (T t in values2)
    {
        int count;
        if (!counts.TryGetValue(t, out count) || count == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        counts[t] = count - 1;
    }

    return true;
}
```

In Python you could use the `Counter` class:

```
>>> a = [1, 4, 9, 4, 6]
>>> b = [4, 6, 1, 4, 9]
>>> c = [4, 1, 9, 1, 6]
>>> d = [1, 4, 6, 9, 4]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(a) == Counter(b)
True
>>> Counter(c) == Counter(d)
False
```

Comment: What if I check if the product is the same?

Comment: @Bruce: That doesn't work either. Consider a simple case where both arrays share at least one zero.

Comment: @Mark: You'd need a `HashMap` to account for duplicated entries.

Comment: @João: Good point. For some reason I had assumed that there would not be duplicates, but the question definitely doesn't state that.

Answer (score 2):

If a space complexity of `O(n)` is not a problem, you can do it in `O(n)`, by first storing in a hash map the number of occurrences for each value in the first array, and then running a second pass on the second array and check that every element exists in the map, decrementing the number the occurrences for each element.

Comment: You have to count them if the arrays are allowed to include duplicates.

Comment: @DonRoby: Yes, I've since changed my answer from a hash set to an hash map to account for that, thanks.

Comment: And now it's the same as my answer.  But have an upvote anyway!

Comment: @Jao so the keys of the Hashmap would be the numbers and the values would be the frequencies ?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is probably a counting one using a map whose keys are the values in your two arrays.

Go through one array creating/incrementing the appropriate map location and go through the other one creating/decrementing the appropriate map location.

If the resulting map consists entirely of zeros, your arrays are equal.

This is O(N), and I don't think you can do better.

I suspect this is approximately what Mark Byers was going for in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the contents of both arrays numerically, and then compare each nth item.

You could also take each item in array1, and then check if it is present in array2. Keep a count of how many matches you find. At the end, the number of matches should equal the length of the arrays.